# How can I include two languages in build.xml of Apache ant builder

Tags: java, scala, build.xml, lang, antbuilder

I want my `ant` builder to build both `Scala` and `Java`. How can I include both the languages in my `lang` field and `includes` field? What delimiter needs to be used? The `target` currently looks like this:

```
<target name="foobar">
  <target lang="java"> [Here I need to include both Scala and Java]
    <classpath>
      <useimport path="imports"/>
    </classpath>
    <source base="src/foobar" includes="**/*.java"/> [Here I need to include both Scala and Java file regex]
  </target>
</target>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: includes="**/*.(java|scala)"

Comment: @Zoltán Nope, that does not work